# Do Matthew 26:29 and Mark 14:25 prove that Jesus took a Nazirite vow?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospels, historical-jesus, john-the-baptist

Matthew 26:29, Mark 14:25 and Luke 22:18 are three New Testament passages that seem to indicate that Christ once took the Nazirite vow (as did Samuel, Samson, and John the Baptist).
It is known that the Nazirite Vow was made as follows: the Nazirite should abstain from wine, corpses and let his hair grow during the period of his vow. Nazirites were specially set apart for God and their long hair was equivalent to a king's crown.
So did Jesus make the vow? Does this prove that Jesus had long hair?

Comment: Jesus was a Nazarene, but He was not a Nazirite. The two terms are often confused for one another…….https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-Nazirite.html

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it is opinion based.

Comment: The three cited scriptures should be explicitly quoted, both because it saves many of us from having to look them up, and because it gives the exact wording of the particular translation that was used, which might affect the answer. Then, given that specific wording, it should say exactly *how* they "*seem to indicate …*".